# How to make PHP for loop with condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I am using PHP to create looping with condition, but the result was not like what I want.

Any help you can provide would be great! :)

```
$cnt = array(
    "08.00","09.00","10.00"
);
$time = array(
    "07.00","08.00","09.00","10.00","11.00","12.00","13.00","14.00",
    "15.00","16.00","17.00","18.00","19.00","20.00","21.00","22.00"
);
```

This is my looping code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 16 ; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3 ; $j++) {
        if ($time[$i] == $cnt[$j]) {
            $button[$i] = 'disable';
        } else {
            $button[$i] = $time[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
07.00 08.00 09.00 disable 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00 19.00 20.00 21.00 22.00
```

And the result i want is:

```
07.00 disable disable disable 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00 19.00 20.00 21.00 22.00
```

Comment: I think you have many answers here. You can accept the only which you think helped you the most and solved your problem. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
$button = array();
foreach($time as $t) {
    if(in_array($t, $cnt, true)) {
        $button[]='disable';
    } else {
        $button[]=$t;
    }
}
```

The loop iterates through all elements of the `$time` array and checks for every value if the array `$cnt` contains the same value.

Since you are added values with incrementing indexes you can use the array push operator `[]=` to append values to the $button array.

Learn more about `in_array()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php and `[]=`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is flawed - you loop on the `$cnt` array and continually set/replace your disabled/time values. Consider this:

```
$time -> looking at 08:00
```

loop on $cnt:

```
08:00 -> matches -> set $button[$i] to disabled
09:00 -> no match -> set $button[$i] to $time[$i]
10:00 -> no match -> set $button[$i] to $time[$i]
```

Your inner loop is destructive - you only save the result of the comparison test from the LAST item in $cnt, therefore your "earlier" test results get destroyed.

What you should have is this:

```
foreach($time as $idx => $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $cnt)) {
        $button[$idx] = 'disabled');
    } else {
        $button[$idx] = $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers show ways of doing this, but there's also the functional approach:

```
$button = array_map(
    function ($item) use ($cnt) {
        return in_array($item, $cnt) ? 'disable' : $item;
    },
    $time
);
```

Comment: Not as short as your answer is are the list of errors you will get with this

Comment: @Rizier123 What do you mean?

Comment: @hek2mgl If you look at the first revision of his answer you see he didn't used `global` nor `use()`. Now magically he went to `global $cnt;` and then to `use($cnt)` i wonder where he got this from

Comment: @Rizier123 Probably you both had the same idea (a good idea) at almost the same time. Always assume good faith!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I go through each element of `$time` with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and check if it is in the array of `$cnt` with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). If it is in the array I replace it with the replacement where I use [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to inherit it from the parent scope and if not i assign the value again)

```
<?php

    $cnt = array("08.00", "09.00", "10.00");
    $time = array("07.00", "08.00", "09.00", "10.00", "11.00", "12.00", "13.00", "14.00", "15.00", "16.00", "17.00", "18.00", "19.00", "20.00", "21.00", "22.00");  
    $replacement = "disabled";

    $time = array_map(function ($v) use ($cnt, $replacement) {
        return (in_array($v, $cnt) ? $replacement : $v);
    }, $time);

    print_r($time);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 07.00 [1] => disabled [2] => disabled [3] => disabled [4] => 11.00 [5] => 12.00 [6] => 13.00 [7] => 14.00 [8] => 15.00 [9] => 16.00 [10] => 17.00 [11] => 18.00 [12] => 19.00 [13] => 20.00 [14] => 21.00 [15] => 22.00 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following, it's not optimal but it changes the least amount of your code while making it work:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 16 ; $i++) { 
     if(in_array($time[$i], $cnt) {
          $button[$i]='disable';
     } else {
          $button[$i]=$time[$i];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP in_array:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 16 ; $i++) { 
    if(in_array( $time[$i], $cnt ){
        $button[$i]='disable';
    }else{
        $button[$i]=$time[$i];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a 'break;' in inner loop. See below,

```
        for ($i=0; $i < 16 ; $i++) { 
            for ($j=0; $j < 3 ; $j++) { 
                if($time[$i]==$cnt[$j]){
                    $button[$i]='disable';
                    break;
                }else{
                    $button[$i]=$time[$i];
                }   
            }
        }
```